# Angular Ng-Bootstrap Datepicker Calendar Day Background color

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

how can I change the 1+ days background color on ng-bootstrap datepicker calendar, in the same way as the color changes when a day is selected.

When a day is selected, it changes the div class to:

```
btn-light bg-primary text-white
```

Let's say that I want several days to appear as

```
btn-light bg-success text-white
```

or

```
btn-light bg-warning text-white
```

How is the best/easiest way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a custom day, see the example in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#customday

if your customDay is like (simply)

```
<ng-template #customDay let-date="date" 
           let-currentMonth="currentMonth" 
           let-selected="selected" let-disabled="disabled" let-focused="focused">
    {{ date.day }}
</ng-template>
```

You can use date,currentMonth,selected,focused or disabled to change the class
e.g.

```
<ng-template #customDay let-date="date" let-currentMonth="currentMonth" let-selected="selected" let-disabled="disabled" let-focused="focused">
  <span [ngClass]="myClass(date)"  [class.focused]="focused"
        [class.bg-primary]="selected" [class.hidden]="date.month !== currentMonth" [class.text-muted]="disabled">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
especialDates:NgbDateStruct[]=[
    {year:2018,month:2,day:1},
    {year:2018,month:2,day:10}]
myClass(date:NgbDateStruct)
{
    let isSelected=this.specialDates
         .find(d=>d.year==date.year && d.month==date.month && d.day==date.day)
    return isSelected?'classSelected':'classNormal'
}
```

see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-vrxfeu

Comment: sorry Eliseo, I couldn't get it to work. Would you kindly share a stackblitz demo?

Comment: try replace "class" by "[ngClass]". Sorry, I'm in hurry, I'll see if after I can share a stackblitz demo

Comment: I edited the code a create a stackblitz demo (it's my first stackblitz demo, I don't know if you can see)

Comment: Ended up using your ng-template model with <ngb-datepicker #d1 [(ngModel)]="model" #c1="ngModel" [dayTemplate]="customDay" ></ngb-datepicker> which works perfectly if you want to display the calendar not in a popup. Thank you Eliseo!

Comment: Is there a way to do this globally for all datepickers?  Want to have the current date hightlighted all the time by adding a class to that day, but for all datepickers instead adding ng-template throughout the application since the datepicker is used a lot