# multiple date picker in angular 4 and no jquery

Tags: angular, typescript, multiple-date-picker

can anyone please tell me how to implement multiple date picker using only angular 4 and typescript. I've found one but it supports only angular1.

Thanks!!

Comment: What will be the issue, whether you are using one or multiple datepciker

Comment: @PardeepJain He needs a single datepicker from which random multiple dates can be selected

Comment: @Prachi yeah!!. I need a single date picker where I can select multiple dates. So that I can send it in an array.

Comment: You can try [PrimeNg Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar). See the example for multiple calendar.

Comment: @Prachi Thank you :) Then OP can use primeng's datepicker

Comment: @PardeepJain Shared the same!

Comment: Im using angular 4 and im getting this error when i'm trying to install prime ng

D:\ankush\myapp>npm i primeng@4.3.0
moya-app@0.0.0 D:\ankush\VITMOBAPPHYD2016
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.3.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.3.3
`-- primeng@4.3.0  invalid

Before this I used npm i primeng . Which is not supported by my angular version

Comment: Need to install prime ng proper version to match angular 4 . Angular common and core is 4.3.3

Comment: It would be a warning I guess. Have you tried running your application?

Comment: @Prachi no they're not warnings . It is not installed at all. I cannot find it in node modules.

Comment: For me, a multiple date picker is only an array of dates and a datePicker captable to show the days in de array. using ng-bootstrap date picker and a custom day like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669728/angular-ng-bootstrap-datepicker-calendar-day-background-color/50669881#50669881. Only you need in change of the datePicker add or remove the date of the array

Answer (score 5):

How make a multi-date-picker based in ng-bootstrap date picker?

I've hardly based on the example of datepicker-range from ng-bootstrap. You can see the final code in: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-he7fsp

As I comment the only thing that we must do is store in an array the selected dates and change the custom-day to show the selected dated in another background

The multi-date-picker.html is very similar to the ng-bootstrap datepicker range

```
<!-- we not use (select)="onDateSelection($event)"-->
<ngb-datepicker #dp  [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t">
</ngb-datepicker>

<ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
  <!--we use (click) event pass the event and the date-->
  <span class="custom-day" (click)="onDateSelection($event,date)"
        [class.focused]="focused"
        [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
        [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
        <!--add a class.selected if the date belong to our dates selected -->
        [class.selected]="isDateSelected(date)"
        (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
        (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

The code is a bit complex but not more. I only add the functions isDateSelected,addRangeDate y addDate. Well, I change the function onDateSelection to take account when the user is pressed Crtl Key

```
import {Component,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDateStruct, NgbCalendar} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

const equals = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
  one && two && two.year === one.year && two.month === one.month && two.day === one.day;

const before = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
  !one || !two ? false : one.year === two.year ? one.month === two.month ? one.day === two.day
    ? false : one.day < two.day : one.month < two.month : one.year < two.year;

const after = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
  !one || !two ? false : one.year === two.year ? one.month === two.month ? one.day === two.day
    ? false : one.day > two.day : one.month > two.month : one.year > two.year;

@Component({
  selector: 'ngb-multi-date-picker',
  templateUrl: 'multi-date-picker.html',
  styles: [`
    .custom-day {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0.185rem 0.25rem;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
    }
    .custom-day.range, .custom-day:hover {
      background-color: rgb(2, 117, 216);
      color: white;
    }
    .custom-day.faded {
      background-color: rgba(2, 117, 216, 0.5);
    }
    .custom-day.selected{  
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);

    }
  `]
})
export class MultiDatePicker {

  hoveredDate: NgbDateStruct;

  fromDate: NgbDateStruct;
  toDate: NgbDateStruct;

  _datesSelected:NgbDateStruct[]=[]; 

  @Input()
  set datesSelected(value:NgbDateStruct[])  
  {
     this._datesSelected=value;
  }
  get datesSelected():NgbDateStruct[]
  {
    return this._datesSelected?this._datesSelected:[];
  }

  @Output() datesSelectedChange=new EventEmitter<NgbDateStruct[]>();

  constructor(calendar: NgbCalendar) {
  }

  onDateSelection(event:any,date: NgbDateStruct) {
    //event is a MouseEvent, we can check if CtrlKey is pressed 
    event.target.parentElement.blur();  //make that not appear the outline
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      if (event.ctrlKey==true)  //If is CrtlKey pressed
        this.fromDate = date;
      else
        this.addDate(date);

      this.datesSelectedChange.emit(this.datesSelected);

    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && after(date, this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
      this.addRangeDate(this.fromDate,this.toDate);
      this.fromDate=null;
      this.toDate=null;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }

  addDate(date:NgbDateStruct)
  {
      let index=this.datesSelected.findIndex(f=>f.day==date.day && f.month==date.month && f.year==date.year);
      if (index>=0)       //If exist, remove the date
        this.datesSelected.splice(index,1);
      else   //a simple push
        this.datesSelected.push(date);
    }
    addRangeDate(fromDate:NgbDateStruct,toDate:NgbDateStruct)
    {
        //We get the getTime() of the dates from and to
        let from=new Date(fromDate.year+"-"+fromDate.month+"-"+fromDate.day).getTime();
        let to=new Date(toDate.year+"-"+toDate.month+"-"+toDate.day).getTime();
        for (let time=from;time<=to;time+=(24*60*60*1000)) //add one day
        {
            let date=new Date(time);
            //javascript getMonth give 0 to January, 1, to February...
            this.addDate({year:date.getFullYear(),month:date.getMonth()+1,day:date.getDate()});
        }   
        this.datesSelectedChange.emit(this.datesSelected);
    }
    //return true if is selected
    isDateSelected(date:NgbDateStruct)
    {
        return (this.datesSelected.findIndex(f=>f.day==date.day && f.month==date.month && f.year==date.year)>=0);
    }
  isHovered = date => this.fromDate && !this.toDate && this.hoveredDate && after(date, this.fromDate) && before(date, this.hoveredDate);
  isInside = date => after(date, this.fromDate) && before(date, this.toDate);
  isFrom = date => equals(date, this.fromDate);
  isTo = date => equals(date, this.toDate);
}
```

How work, just we have

```
<ngb-multi-date-picker [datesSelected]="datesSelected"
         (datesSelectedChange)="change($event)"></ngb-multi-date-picker>
```

and

```
export class AppComponent {
  datesSelected:NgbDateStruct[]=[]; 
  change(value:NgbDateStruct[])
  {
    this.datesSelected=value;
  }
```

Comment: This is working like charm . Could you please provide some inputs how can I use maxDate or minDate here? To disable all past days or future days of a given date.

Comment: @NabaragPaul, see that is esencially a ngb-datePicker. Ende you can use the properties of this, e.g. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#limiting-dates. The only thing is improve the code to pass as @ Input and use in the html

Comment: Thanks for this module. Its working like a beast.